# Intellij replace all occurances of stringbuilder.toString()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I would like to find all occurances of toString method that belongs to StringBuilder :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("sometext");
return sb.toString();
```

And replace it with:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("sometext");
return Optimizer.stat(sb.toString());
```

Of course the var "sb" is not always written the same way :-)

I tried IntelliJ Ultimate Structural Search and Replace. But I could not find a way to only get toString of StringBuilder class.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Intellij structural search use the pattern:

```
return $sb$.toString();
```

replacing with

```
return Optimizer.stat($sb$.toString());
```

Now, hit "Edit Variables", select `sb`, and set "Expression type (regexp)" to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: works very well, but if i remove the "return" it does not find any. shouldn't it find the same amount plus all the places where the value is used within the same method?

Comment: If you return the `return`, you'd need to remove the `;` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it now. InteliJ was busy for 20 min. with 3GB memory. :-)

Comment: @Hasan better intellij for 20min than you for... Much longer!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not complain. Just wanted to mention how much work it saved me.